# The function of TIME in longitudinal MLM

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures, spss, panel-data, multilevel-analysis

I am conducting longitudinal multilevel models with Daily observations as level-1 variable and PARTICIPANT as level-2 variable. Predictors and outcome variables are measured every day.

I am confused about the use of TIME in SPSS syntax. Models that I find use TIME both as a predictor and as the level-1 identifier. Is this appropriate?

Some models include the following row and some dont:

/REPEATED=time | SUBJECT(Participant) COVTYPE (ar1)

Some of them only add TIME as a predictor without the row above.

What is the correct way to write SPSS syntax if I want to indicate that TIME is the level-1 measurement unit? Is the command above indispensable? Do I need to /can I also add TIME as a predictor (fixed or random effect).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use time as both the index for REPEATED and as a fixed predictor. REPEATED sets up the R matrix structure in the mixed model. There are different ways to handle the repeated measures, some involving using REPEATED, some involving just RANDOM effects. Multiple approaches can be valid.